# How to set two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this in HTML/CSS:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEADER DIV                                                          |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|    nav DIV |   scrollable DIV                                       |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
|            |                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FOOTER DIV                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- Header and footer div are browser window width.
- header and footer and fixed height in pixels
- header and footer and fixed on the top and bottom of the browser
  window nav div is the height of the browser window minus (header height +
  footer height)
- scrollable content is scrolling internally, without affecting the
  absolute position of hte footer or header.

I can only get to a point where both nav DIV + and scrollable DIV scroll together.
I can't make the NAV div not scroll while the scrollable DIV scrolls.

I guess the key is how I put the two divs side by side and yet not scroll one of them when the other scrolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style> 
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container { position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 1000px; } 
.header { height: 10%; width: 100%; } 
.wrapper { width: 100%; height: 80%; } 
.wrapper .nav { width: 20%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; } 
.wrapper .scrollable { width: 80%; margin-left:-4px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; overflow-y: scroll; } 
.footer { height: 10px; width: 100%; } 
</style>

<body> 
  <div class="container">    
       <div class="header"></div>    
       <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="nav">
          </div>
          <div class="scrollable">
          </div>    
       </div>    
       <div class="footer"></div> 
      </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand why `width: 1000px;` in `.container`.  Why do that?  (FYI, this answer was *very* helpful to me.)

Answer (score 0):

```
nav
{
 margin-left:0px;
 width:100px;
}

scrollable
{
 margin-left:100px;
}
```

---

### OR

```
    .container
    {
        width:800px;
    }
    .nav{
      width: 300px;
      float: left;
    }
    .scrollable        {
       width: 500px;
       float:right;
    }

HTML File
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">left content</div>
  <div class="scrollable">right content</div>
</div>
```

Try this i hope it may help you !